# In PHP and Oracle, when echoing the variable it does not show the value

Tags: php, oracle

I save Oracle query to table.

tbl QueryData

```
queryid | query_info
001     | SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM WA_GA_TBL_USERS WHERE TO_CHAR(USERPASSWORD_EXPIREDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '$getBeforeMonth'
002     | SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM WA_GA_TBL_DEPARTMENTS
```

PHP

```
$getBeforeMonth = "2017-07-26";

$qWidgetAccess = oci_parse($c1, "
    SELECT
    W.WIDGETID,
    W.WIDGETNAME,
    W.WIDGETDESCRIPTION,
    W.WIDGETSTATUS,
    W.PROJECTID_FK,
    W.WIDGETQUERY,
    W.WIDGETICON,
    W.PROJECTID_FK,
    AW.WIDGETID_FK,
    AW.GROUPID_FK,
    AW.DATEADDED,
    P.PROJECTID,
    P.PROJECTNAME
    FROM
    WA_GA_TBL_WIDGETS W,
    WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSWIDGETS AW,
    WA_GA_TBL_PROJECTS P
    WHERE
    W.WIDGETID = AW.WIDGETID_FK AND
    W.PROJECTID_FK = P.PROJECTID AND
    AW.GROUPID_FK = '" . $getGroupIDFK . "' AND
    W.WIDGETSTATUS = '2'
    ORDER BY AW.DATEADDED DESC
");
oci_execute($qWidgetAccess);
while($dWidgetAccess = oci_fetch_array($qWidgetAccess))
{
?>
     <div class="textWidget">
        <div class="total">
        <?php
        $qTotal = oci_parse($c1, $dWidgetAccess['WIDGETQUERY']);
        oci_execute($qTotal);
        $dTotal = oci_fetch_array($qTotal);

        echo $dTotal['TOTAL'];
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="title"><?php echo $dWidgetAccess['WIDGETNAME']; ?></div>

    <div class="projectName">
        <?php echo $dWidgetAccess['PROJECTNAME']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

When I run the query, it only working for queryid 002. Query 001 no result and when I try to print it, it show $getBeforeMonth, it should be 2017-07-26.

Why does this happen?

Comment: try to change conversion from to_char on table column (it could be index on it) to to_date on your variable: SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM WA_GA_TBL_USERS WHERE USERPASSWORD_EXPIREDATE <= to_date('$getBeforeMonth','YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: Why it happened? Well, why should your Oracle DB (server) substitute your PHP (client) variable during `oci_parse()` call? You should find a different way of dealing with parametrizing your stored queries.